# Designing an accumulating Tensorflow GPU operator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm designing a GPU op kernel that iteratively accumulates data in a buffer of GPU memory.
It's important that the data remains in GPU memory. So something along the lines of:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    buffer = tf.zeros(...)

    buffer = accumulate(param11, param12, buffer)
    buffer = accumulate(param21, param22, buffer)
    buffer = accumulate(param31, param32, buffer)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    A = do_some_more_stuff(buffer)
```

I'd like some input on three approaches that I think can be used to accomplish this:

1. Allocate output tensor on each call and use that as an input tensor
   on the next call. This is simple to implement but I'm concerned that
   continual allocation of GPU memory will be an issue.
   Will tensorflow release now unused allocations into the GPU memory pool?

   ```
   REGISTER_OP("Accumulate")
       .Input("param1: T")
       .Input("param2: T")
       .Input("buffer_in: T")
       .Output("buffer_out: T")

   void Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext * ctx) override
   {
       TensorShape output_shape{...};
       Tensor * output_ptr = nullptr;
       OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output(
           0, output_shape, &output_ptr))

       kernel<<<grid, blocks, 0, stream>>>(
           ctx->input(0), ctx->input(1),
           output);
   }
   ```
2. Reference input and output tensors and ensure they're referring
   to the same data. As I understand the standard ops and OpKernelContext
   documentation, this needs to be protected with a mutex as other ops
   may also be accessing the underlying referenced tensor...

   ```
   REGISTER_OP("Accumulate")
       .Input("param1: T")
       .Input("param2: T")
       .Input("buffer_in: Ref(T)")
       .Output("buffer_out: Ref(T)")

   void Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext * ctx) override
   {
       mutex_lock(mu_);

       ctx->forward_ref_input_to_ref_output(2, 0);

       kernel<<<grid, blocks, 0, stream>>>(
           ctx->input(0), ctx->input(1),
           ctx->mutable_input(2, true));
   }
   ```
3. Use allocate_persistent() in conjunction with an OpKernelConstruction context
   to provide a persistent buffer for accumulation. I'd prefer not to do this because
   I'm dealing with variable buffer sizes and they'll probably be fairly large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with your C++ code, but from looking at the python snippet I think `tf.assign` might help. It allows you to do things like this:

```
buffer = tf.Variable(...)
param = tf.Variable(...)
accumulate_op = buffer.assign(expr<param, buffer>)

...

sess.run(accumulate_op)
```

Running `accumulate_op` should update your buffer on the gpu (you may have to wrap it in a `tf.group` to avoid fetching the updated value).